# LCM problem with remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let us find the least number divisible by $13$ such that when that number divided by $8,12,16,20$ it leaves remainder $1$ in all cases

$help !$ $Answer$ $4812$ $how ?$

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the [Chinese Remainder Theorem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  Note that $1$ satisfies the last half and solutions to the last half recur at intervals of $\operatorname{LCM}(8,12,16,20)=240$ so you want a number of the form $240k+1$ that is a multiple of $13$.  As the remainder on dividing $240$ by $13$ is $6$, you need two of them because $1+6+6=13$.  The answer is $481$.

Answer (score 0):

These are the given conditions.

\begin{align}
   N \equiv 0 \pmod{13} \\
   N \equiv 1 \pmod{ 8} \\
   N \equiv 1 \pmod{12} \\
   N \equiv 1 \pmod{16} \\
   N \equiv 1 \pmod{20} \\
\end{align}

The last four conditions can be simplified to one condition.

\begin{array}{r|ccc|c}
   & 2 & 3 & 5 \\
\hline
8  & 2^3 & 1   & 1 \\
12 & 2^2 & 3^1 & 1 \\
16 & 2^4 & 1   & 1 \\
20 & 2^2 & 1   & 5^1 \\
\hline
   &2^4  & 3^1 & 5^1 & 240
\end{array}

$$\operatorname{lcm}(8,12,16,20) = 240$$

\begin{align}
   N \equiv 0 \pmod{13} \\
   N \equiv 1 \pmod{240} \\
\end{align}

From the first congruence, we know that $N = 13n$. From the second we know that
$13n \equiv 1 \pmod{240}$.

\begin{align}
    13n &\equiv 1 \pmod{240} \\
    13n &= 240m + 1 \\
    13n &= 13\cdot 18m + 6m + 1 \\
   6m+1 &\equiv 0 \pmod{13} \\
     6m &\equiv 12 \pmod{13} \\
      m &= 2 \\
    13n &= 240 \cdot 2 + 1 \\
    13n &= 481 \\
      N &= 481 \\
\end{align}

So $\color{\red}{N = 481}$.